# Cannot convert from void to String

Tags: java

Driver class:

```
String world = methods.printHelloWorld("Hello, world!");
{
    System.out.println(world);
}
```

method class:

```
public void printHelloWorld(String world)
{
    world = "Hello, world!";
}
```

Prompt: (part of a larger project)

*void printHelloWorld()*

*Parameters: none*

*Return nothing. Directly prints to System.out the String "Hello, world!"*

I'm getting the error that I cannot convert from `void` to `String`. I can't use a return in my method class. I know I can change `public void printHelloWorld(String world)` `to public String printHelloWorld(String world)`, but that isn't what my teacher wants us to do. (I tried those already)

Comment: Why don't you just call the method without assigning it to anything?

Comment: Hint: Pass by Value vs Pass by Reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is very clear: **You cannot convert from void to String.**

This is how you can achieve what you are trying to do:

```
public void printHelloWorld(String world) {
    System.out.println(world);
}
```

Then

```
methods.printHelloWorld("Hello, world!");
```

Comment: A side note: It's not an exception, it's a compile-time error :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert to a `String` because there's nothing to convert. A return type of `void` means "does not return a value".

Also, you can assign values inside a method to a formal parameter all you want (unless it is declared `final`) and it won't change the value of the actual parameter used in the call to the method.

Perhaps you were trying to do this:

```
String world = "Hello, world!";
methods.printHelloWorld(world);
```

and

```
public void printHelloWorld(String world)
{
    System.out.println(world);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can change public void printHelloWorld(String world) to public String printHelloWorld(String world), but that isn't what my teacher wants us to do. (I tried those already)

Then you can print inside the method itself. Something like:

```
public void printHelloWorld(String world)
{
    System.out.println(world);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printHelloWorld(String world)
{
    world = "Hello, world!";
    System.out.println(world);
}
```

Comment: Please include an explanation along with your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

in method Class have

```
  public static String world = "Hello, world!";
```

in driver class

```
 String world1 = methods.world;
 System.out.println(world1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return String

```
public String printHelloWorld(String world)
{
    world = "Hello, world!";
    return world;
}
```

or Simply

```
public String printHelloWorld(String world)
{
    return "Hello, world!";
}
```

Cheers !!